# Magento 2: Cart price rule Actions dynamically add text field using UI Components

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3.5, dynamic, add, text-field

I have need to add dynamic text field in cart price rule edit section. when click on `Add` button text field should be added. And save data in `salesrule` table.

When select from Apply `Percent Discount: Buy Min N Products` then only this text field should be display else hide it.

I have created one field in `salesrule` table for save data. Need to implement Add multiple text field in cart price rule using UI Components when click on Add button.

I have checked but we can do this thing in system.xml but I need to do in UI Components for cart price rule action section.

**Admin Path:**
`Admin > Marketing > Promotions > Cart Price Rules > Edit > Actions`

[image]

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/DataProvider.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Rule;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider;
use Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\DataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var $collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider
     */
    protected $metadataValueProvider;

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var DecoderInterface
     */
    protected $jsonDecoder;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param ValueProvider $metadataValueProvider
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        Registry $registry,
        ValueProvider $metadataValueProvider,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = [],
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor = null,
        DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->metadataValueProvider = $metadataValueProvider;
        $meta = array_replace_recursive($this->getMetadataValues(), $meta);
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor ?? \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            DataPersistorInterface::class
        );
        $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
        parent::__construct(
            $name,
            $primaryFieldName,
            $requestFieldName,
            $collectionFactory,
            $registry,
            $metadataValueProvider,
            $meta,
            $data,
            $dataPersistor
        );
    }
    
    protected function getMetadataValues()
    {
        $rule = $this->coreRegistry->registry(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_SALES_RULE);
        return $this->metadataValueProvider->getMetadataValues($rule);
    }
    
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        /** @var Rule $rule */
        foreach ($items as $rule) {
            $rule->load($rule->getId());
            $rule->setDiscountAmount($rule->getDiscountAmount() * 1);
            $rule->setDiscountQty($rule->getDiscountQty() * 1);

            $this->loadedData[$rule->getId()] = $rule->getData();
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('sale_rule');
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $rule = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $rule->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$rule->getId()] = $rule->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('sale_rule');
        }       
        $jsonData = $rule->getQtyDiscount();
        if ($jsonData != '') {
            $discountArray = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($jsonData);
            foreach ($discountArray as $key => $discount) {
                $discountData[] = ["qty_discount" => $discount['qty_discount'], "record_id" => $key];
            }
            $this->loadedData[$rule->getId()]['qty'] = $discountData;
        }        
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your custom dynamic fields to the sales rule form by customizing the `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_rule_form.xml` file.

To customize the above file, we need to create a custom module and customize this file in the below path:

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_rule_form.xml
```

The customization code should be like the below code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="actions" sortOrder="30">

        <dynamicRows name="dynamic_rows" sortOrder="0">
            <settings>
                <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Record</addButtonLabel>
                <additionalClasses>
                    <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
                </additionalClasses>
                <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
            </settings>
            <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <field name="field_1" formElement="input">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <validation>
                            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                        </validation>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <label>Field #1</label>
                    </settings>
                </field>

                <actionDelete template="Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <additionalClasses>
                            <class name="some-class">true</class>
                        </additionalClasses>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <label>Actions</label>
                        <componentType>actionDelete</componentType>
                    </settings>
                </actionDelete>
            </container>
        </dynamicRows>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The output will look like this:

[image]

To save the custom field in `salesrule` table:

The salesrules are saved into the salesrule table by `sales_rule/promo_quote/save` controller. You can find this controller by looking into the network tab while saving the rule. Pls check the attached screenshot

[image]

From that above controller, we can now know the controller page. The controller path will be `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Controller/Adminhtml/Promo/Quote/Save.php`

From the above `Save.php` file, you can find a line `$model->save();` which means, the `salesrule` table Model and resource Model are:

Model => `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule.php`
ResourceModel => `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/ResourceModel/Rule.php`

Every table data is saved from the ResourceModel's `save` method. So we can customize the `save` method to inject our new data. For this follow the below steps:

Step 1:

Declare a plugin for `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/ResourceModel/Rule.php` class `save` method in your custom module.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
        <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule">
            <plugin name="before_save_rule" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\BeforeSaveCartRule" sortOrder="10"/>
        </type>
    </config>
```

Step 2: create a plugin class and write the save logic method:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/BeforeSaveCartRule.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule;

class BeforeSaveCartRule
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;

    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function beforeSave(Rule $subject, $object) {
        $data = $this->request->getPostValue();

        $convertedToJson = json_encode($data['dynamic_rows']);
        $object->setCustomField($convertedToJson); /*Here you have to mention your custom field name. 
                                                    For example if the custom field is multiple_actions then the method should be like setMultipleActions()*/

        return null;
    }
}
```

In the below screenshot you can see, how your custom dynamic fields data is posted from request. I saved this custom field by converting it into an JSON and saved in custom field. You can customise it as per your need and save it.

[image]

Once you saved the salesrule you can check your salesrule table and you can see the saved custom field value

Result:
[image]

**Note**: Once you saved the salesrule you cannot find the saved data into your sales rule admin form. Only you can find the data in your database `salesrule` table, because you might need some dataprovider customisation to fetch and display the data into your custom dynamic row field.

Comment: Thank you @Siranjeevi K S  But how to save data and fetch data in this dynamic row. we need to save it in 'salesrule' table to add one custom field.

Comment: @Kirti Nariya I updated my answer, please check

Comment: Thank you. It's fine. Facing issue for fetch data while edit form. As you said use  dataprovide for fetch and display data in admin edit rule. I have try this but not fetching data in edit rule for dynamic row.

Comment: Please let me know if you have idea about fetch dynamic row data from salesrule table in cart rule edit.

Comment: Can you update your dataprovider customization code? and let me know what was the exact issue you are facing

Comment: I have updated my question with Dataprovider. I can't get any data. Please check.

Comment: I have fixed issue for fetch data and updated my dataprovider in question.